# Build issue with vite related to styled component

Tags: css, reactjs, build, styled-components, vite

I am getting below error while budling for production using vite , The build is working fine locally .

Here is the error ,

> Error: [vite]: Rollup failed to resolve import "react-is" from "../../node_modules/styled-components/dist/styled-components.browser.esm.js".

Can anyone please suggest

I tried to add below plugin in vite config js but its not working

```
    plugins: [
      react({
        babel: {
          plugins: [
            [
              "babel-plugin-styled-components",
              {
                displayName: true,
                fileName: false,
              },
            ],
          ],
        },
      }),
    ];
```